# GNU/Debian Linux and LD

Tags: linux, libraries, ld, dynamic-library

Lets say I have a massive project which consists of multiple dynamic libraries that will all get installed to /usr/lib or /usr/lib64. Now lets say that one of the libraries call into another of the compiled libraries. If I place both of the libraries that are dependent on eachother in the same location will the ld program be able to allow the two libraries to call eachother?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is perhaps yes, but it is a **very bad design to have circular references between two libraries** (i.e. `liba.so` containing function `fa`, calling function `fb` from `libb.so`, calling function `ga` from `liba.so`).

You should merge the two libraries in one `libbig.so`. And don't worry, libraries can be quite big. (some corporations have Linux libraries of several hundred megabytes of code).

The `gold` linker from package `binutils-gold` on Debian should be useful to you. It works faster than the older linker from `binutils`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as their location is present in set of directories `ld` searches for libraries in. You can override this set by using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` enviroment variable.

See [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) manual, it will resolve your questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the runtime dynamic linker /lib/ld-linux* (as opposed to /usr/bin/ld), it will look for libraries in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which typically includes /usr/lib and /usr/lib64.

In general, /lib/ld-* are used for .so libraries at run-time; /usr/bin/ld is used for .a libraries at compile-time.

However, if your libraries are using dlopen() or similar to find one another (e.g. plug-ins), they may have other mechanisms for finding one another. For example, many plug-in systems will use dlopen to read every library in a certain (one or many) directory/ies.